# JavaFX - How to check user input in editable TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I am wanting to check that the user has entered an integer, if a string is entered or the field is blank I want to display an error.

I am currently getting a NumberFormatException when entering a string in the console but cannot figure out where to add a try catch to.

This is an example of one of my columns, the others follow the same style:

```
regularityColumn.setMinWidth(130);
      regularityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>
              ("taskTypeRegularity"));
table.getColumns().addAll(....., regularityColumn);
```

If a manager user is found the table is set to editable along with the following:

```
regularityColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(
                new IntegerStringConverter()));
    regularityColumn.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
        TaskType selectedTask = table.getSelectionModel()
                    .getSelectedItem();
        selectedTask.setTaskTypeRegularityInt(e.getNewValue());
});
```

Comment: What about adding a 'try .. catch' statement inside the lambda expression for setOnEditCommit? Between the '{' and '}'

Comment: I've tried that, it seems like the exception happens before that stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own StringConverter.  The exception is coming from the `IntegerStringConverter`.

So replace this...

```
regularityColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(
            new IntegerStringConverter()));
```

with something like this...

```
regularityColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(
            new StringConverter<Integer>(){
            Integer fromString(String s) {
                 //convert the string to integer yourself and catch the exception
            }

            String toString(Integer i) {
                 //convert the integer to String yourself and catch the exception
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Please note I typed the code without an IDE, so excuse any typos.  If you will use this in multiple places, then turn it into its own class that can be re-used, e.g. `MyIntegerStringConverter`.

Comment: Where would I add the 'setOnEditCommit' parts, I can't get that to work now

Comment: The exception is now working but the column on the GUI is now empty. This is my code: https://i.imgur.com/S4Qmkrh.png

Comment: Dude you are not suppose to return NULL in those methods.  That's why your column is empty.